# Enabling JAAS based single sign on (SSO) for custom java applications on hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, single-sign-on, kerberos, jaas

We have developed few applications (written in Java) that would consume services  of Kafka, spark, Yarn and HDFS. Currently our cluster is not security enabled and we are planning to enable the security shortly. These applications are run using spark-submit (through Yarn). Once these services are kerberos'd, I would like to know if we can use JAAS based Single Sign On (SSO) to access these services.Our plan is to create a common java package that will handle this authentication and authorization for all the services. Is that possible? An example would really help. I already looked at examples from oracle site and other blogs but it is always pointing to LDAP authorization but nothing specific to hadoop

Comment: It won't solve your specific issue, but it's a recommended reading: *"Kerberos and Hadoop, the Madness beyond the Gate"* https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/

Comment: AFAIK the `spark-submit` shell command requires *(a)* a valid Kerberos ticket in the cache defined by `$KRB5CCNAME`, and the tricky part will be to prevent jobs for different users to access the same cache by mistake; or *(b)* a keytab that contains the appropriate password (for creation of a private Kerberos ticket for the Spark session, via `--principal` / `--keytab`) but that option is clearly not for you.

Comment: Note that `spark-submit` prepares the setup for a "launcher" process which manages the initial Kerberos auth and gets some Hadoop auth tokens, then launches the "driver" -- either in the same JVM *(local or client mode)* or on a distant node *(cluster mode)* -- which launches the "executors" etc. -- it works, but it's brittle.

Comment: @samson thank you for the response. I will read through the link shared.